# What are the components in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frameworks

I was reading about components and directives in angular.js but I couldn't get the exact difference between these two and also I want to know about the advantage of these two?
can anyone explain it?

Comment: Start with https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial (or at this point ideally https://angular.io/tutorial/, AngularJS is no longer supported).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be useful for you.

[image]

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-directive-and-component-in-angularjs/#:~:text=Component%20is%20used%20to%20break,a%20total%20component%2Dbased%20model](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-directive-and-component-in-angularjs/#:%7E:text=Component%20is%20used%20to%20break,a%20total%20component%2Dbased%20model).